# Как получить все результаты запроса mysql codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, codeigniter

Необходимо из базы получить все результаты выборки но codeigniter возвращает только первый.

controller:

```
    public function gifts() {

    $data = $this->product_model->getGiftsProducts();

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('header_search');
    $this->load->view('test_gifts' , $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
  }
```

model:

```
    public function getGiftsProducts() {
    $this->db->select('pro_title, price , products_offers.barcode , photo_id');
    //$this->db->where('products_offers.barcode' , '0093700');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('products_offers' , 'products.ind_id = products_offers.ind_id' );

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result_array();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data = array(
                'title' => $row->pro_title,
                'price' => $row->price,
                'barcode' => $row->barcode,
                'image_code' => $row->photo_id
            );
        }

    return $data;
}
```

view:

```
  <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>static/pic/150x240/<?= $image_code ?>/1_1.jpg">
  <?php echo '<p>' .$title. '</p>'; ?>
  <?php echo '<p>' .$price. '</p>'; ?>
  <?php echo '<p>' .$barcode. '</p>'; ?>
```

Пробовал передать $query->result() || $query->result_array() во view и вывести с помощью foreach однако не работает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модель

```
    public function getGiftsProducts() {
    $this->db->select('pro_title, price , products_offers.barcode , photo_id');
    //$this->db->where('products_offers.barcode' , '0093700');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('products_offers' , 'products.ind_id = products_offers.ind_id' );

    $query = $this->db->get();

   return $query->result();
}
```

Контроллер

```
    public function gifts() {

if  ($res = $this->product_model->getGiftsProducts()) {
        $data['gifts'] = $res; }

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('header_search');
    $this->load->view('test_gifts' , $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
```

Шаблон

```
<?php if(isset($gifts)) : ?>
<?php foreach($gifts as $gift) : ?>
<img src="<?= base_url(); ?>static/pic/150x240/<?= $gift->photo_id ?>/1_1.jpg">
  <?php echo '<p>' .$gift->pro_title. '</p>'; ?>
  <?php echo '<p>' .$gift->$price. '</p>'; ?>
  <?php echo '<p>' .$gift->$barcode. '</p>'; ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Единственное шаблон корректно работает если выводить так: `код`    <li>
      <?php echo '<a href="'. $gift-> .'"><img src="'.base_url().'static/pic/150x240/'.$gift->photo_id.'/1_1.jpg"> <p>' .$gift->price. '</p><p></br>' .$gift->pro_title. '</p>'; ?>
    </li>

Comment: В противном случае ( как и Вас в примере ) получаю рандомный результат.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю надо вот так,

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
     $data[] = array(
```

Дело в том, что `$data = array(` просто присваивает массив переменной `$data`, а `$data[] = array(` присваивает новый элемент массива к массиву `$data`.